# I am not able to use internet in my Android Emulator. Even though it will show 3G connection

Tags: android-emulator

I am not able to access internet in my Android Emulator, I give the Internet permission in Manifest file. Even I am not able to open any site in the default browser.

When I use URL in my application then it will display "**request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol**" error.

And when I use default browser then it will display "**07-28 12:09:57.434: ERROR/Tab(607): onReceivedError -2 http://www.google.com/m?client=ms-android-google&source=android-home The URL could not be found.**" error.

It is also display "**07-28 14:05:01.501: ERROR/ActivityThread(295): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**" error

Please anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly check, if you set proxy settings in your emulator or not .For that **settings->Wireless** and **networks->mobile networks->access points->Telkila** .Here you can set proxy and port for your system. Then try to browse Google or other site in your emulator browser.